# How to compare the elements on two arrays on C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

A c ++ problem where I have to determine if the user hit the target. After entering the coordinates of where enemies coulb be, the user then enters more coordinates and I must compare them, print YES if the element[i] of the attacks matches any element of enemies [n]. I know that I'm comparing positions and not elements that's why it's not working but I'm lost.I also tried to solve it by making only one array but it felt better this way.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    int n, k, b;
    int enemies[];
    int attacks[];
    
    cin>>n;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        cin>>b;
        enemies[i]=b;
    }
    
    cin>>k; 
    for (int i=0; i<k; i++) {
        cin>>b;
        atacks[i]=b;
    }
    
    for(int i=0; i<k; i++){
       if(atacks[i]==enemies[i]){
                cout<<"YES"<<endl;
       }
       else{
           cout<<"NO"<<endl;
       }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside from the not-correct array as drescherjm mentioned, you can compare each attack against all the enemies to see if it matches one for a naive O(n*k) solution.

Comment: Thanks I actually changed it for int enemies[10001] and same with atacks because the problem sets that limit.

Comment: If the attack coordinates are entered in the same order, since you are using Plain-Old Arrays, you can use `memcmp()` to compare a fixed number of bytes from each array efficiently. If they are not in any fixed order -- the you are stuck iterating over each of the elements.

Comment: @drescherjm: I disagree. As it stands right now, I'm reasonably certain it simply shouldn't compile (and at least with g++,clang++ or VC++, it won't).

Answer (score 1):

Your code likely doesn't work because this line:

```
if(atacks[i]==enemies[i])
```

requires that matching `attack` and `enemy` should have the same index in their arrays.

As suggested in the comments, you need to iterate over ALL `enemies` for EACH `attack`, which is "O(n*k) solution"

Comment: That would normally be written as an O(n*m) solution. In big-O notation, `k` is *usually* used to mean a constant (so `O(n * k)` is really the same as `O(n)`).

Comment: @JerryCoffin - agree; I was simply quoting one of the comments above :)